# SSAS MDX Parameter Error

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssas, mdx, ssas-2008-r2

In SSRS, I've created a dataset connecting to an AS datasource. I've written up a MDX statement in the query designer and it works fine, until I substitute

```
STRTOMEMBER('[....]')
```

with

```
STRTOMEMBER(@Parameter1)
```

I've also got @Parameter1 defined in the Query Parameter section of the query designer, but I get the following error.

> Messaging-handling subsystem. The message manager for the default locale cannot be found. The locale will be changed to US English. Errors in the metadata manager. The configuration property updates were not persisted. Message-handling subsystem. The message manager for the the 3081 locale cannot be found. Parser: The query contains the Parameter1 parameter, which is not declared. (msmgdsrv)

I've defininately checked the parameter names and they all look correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
STRTOSET(@Parameter1, CONSTRAINED)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just found out the issue. I had defined the Parameter as @Parameter1. It should have been defined as Parameter1. All working now.